# Why doesn't my constructor work? Java

Tags: java, command-line, constructor

For some reason it keeps saying:

> error: '.class' expected

and

> error: ';' expected

```
public class num1{

    public static void main(String args[]) 
        throws java.io.IOException {

            char let;    
            num1 (char l) {     
                let=l;
            }       
            l = (char) System.in.read();        
    }
}
```

Comment: That is not a constructor, that is a main(). A constructor takes the form YourClassName(possible variables) { things to do}

Comment: What command(s) is/are producing that output?

Comment: Is that how your code is indented in your text editor?

Comment: You are going to need the keyword `new` in there somewhere if you are trying to make an object of `num1`.

Comment: You are way far from what you are asking

Comment: There are many problems with this code. I strongly suggest you buy a good Java book written for beginners or spend some time reading the official Oracle tutorials.

Comment: [this](http://www.learnjavaonline.org/) could help you

Answer (score 2):

Num1 is a constructor so keep it outside main.nested methods or methods inside methods are not allowed in java. As constructor is also a method so you can not define constructor in main

Answer (score 0):

Commented above, but here's a little more help.

A Constructor is intended to do something when a class is instantiated. The method you have in your code, public static void main(), makes that class executable - these are two very different things. A constructor for your class would look like this

```
public num1(possible variables)
{
    Things to do with said variables
}
```

I suggest you do some reading before you delve further into the depths of Java, lest you become lost amidst the important differences in basic terminology and syntax.

[This](http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/index.html) reference is an excellent place for beginning Java coders. It takes you through, chapter by chapter, in a very well organized and well explained manner.

The link again, just in case: 
http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor doesn't go in your `main()` method, this

```
public class num1{
  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    char let;    
    num1 (char l) {     
      let=l;
    }       
    l = (char) System.in.read();        
  }
}
```

Should almost certainly be (and use Java naming conventions please - so `Num1`) something like,

```
public class Num1 {
  char let; // <-- char is a primitive type. lowercase. 
            //     Character is an object wrapper for char.
  Num1 (char l) { // <-- package level permission     
    let=l;
  }       
  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    Num1 n = new Num1((char) System.in.read());
    System.out.println(n);        
  }
  @Override 
  public String toString() {
    return String.valueOf(let);
  }
}
```